# Reducing to a single column in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below DF with me . Here the columns are dynamically created based on slots.(1,2,3,4...etc)

```
scala> df1.show
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID|1_count|2_count|3_count|4_count|1_per|2_per|3_per|4_per|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|      3|     11|     15|      3|   70|   80|  150|   20|
|  2|     19|      5|     15|      3|  150|   80|  200|   43|
|  3|     30|     15|     15|     39|   55|   80|  150|  200|
|  4|      8|     65|      3|      3|   70|   80|  150|   55|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Created by -

```
val df1=Seq(
(1,3,11,15,3,70,80,150,20),
(2,19,5,15,3,150,80,200,43),
(3,30,15,15,39,55,80,150,200),
(4,8,65,3,3,70,80,150,55)
)toDF("ID","1_count","2_count","3_count","4_count","1_per","2_per","3_per","4_per")
```

I need to select the first occurrence of the per and count where per <100 where count >10. This should be a row level operation ie for each ID.

Expected output

```
+---+-------+----+----+
| ID|  count|per |slot|
+---+-------+----+----+
|  1|     11|  80|  2 |
|  2|      0|  0 |  0 |
|  3|     30| 55 |  1 |
|  4|     65|  80|  2 |
+---+-------+----+----+
```

The logic of output ID is to find the first column values **(x_count ,x_per)** which meet the criteria (where per <100 and count >10 )

Comment: Can you explain logic to get  the output. how `_per` for ID 1 is 80 and for 2 is 0 and logic for slot?

Comment: whats the logic for slot ?

Comment: slot - expains from which column the data is populated , like 1_count/1_per OR 2_count/2_per etc ...

Comment: I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean solution can be with using `UDF`

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, 3, 11, 15, 3, 70, 80, 150, 20),
  (2, 19, 5, 15, 3, 150, 80, 200, 43),
  (3, 30, 15, 15, 39, 55, 80, 150, 200),
  (4, 8, 65, 3, 3, 70, 80, 150, 55)
)
.toDF("ID", "1_count", "2_count", "3_count", "4_count", "1_per", "2_per", "3_per", "4_per")

//combine all the count and per coluns in a array
val allCols = df1.columns.filter(_.contains("_count")).map(col)
  .zip(df1.columns.filter(_.contains("_per")).map(col))
  .map(x => array(x._1, x._2))

//UDF to extract the first matched or 0 in case of unmatched
val findFirstOccur = udf((all: Seq[Seq[Int]]) => {
  all.zipWithIndex.filter(r => {
    if (r._1(0) > 10 && r._1(1) < 100) true else false
  }).map(x => (x._1(0), x._1(1), x._2 + 1)).headOption.getOrElse((0,0,0))
})

//New column with udf 
val df2 = df1.withColumn("a", findFirstOccur(array(allCols: _*)))
    .select(($"ID"), $"a._1"as("count"), $"a._2".as("per"), $"a._3".as("slot"))
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+---+----+
|ID |count|per|slot|
+---+-----+---+----+
|1  |11   |80 |2   |
|2  |0    |0  |0   |
|3  |30   |55 |1   |
|4  |65   |80 |2   |
+---+-----+---+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Load your dataframe
2. Map the columns to array columns count to countArr , perArr
3. Add a row mapper to iterate through column and to find first matching entry
4. Map the row to newly matched column or default (rowid,0,0,0)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import scala.collection.mutable

object PerCount {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = Constant.getSparkSess

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = List((1, 3, 11, 15, 3, 70, 80, 150, 20),
      (2, 19, 5, 15, 3, 150, 80, 200, 43),
      (3, 30, 15, 15, 39, 55, 80, 150, 200),
      (4, 8, 65, 3, 3, 70, 80, 150, 55)
    ).toDF("ID", "1_count", "2_count", "3_count", "4_count", "1_per", "2_per", "3_per", "4_per")

    val countArrayColumns = List("1_count", "2_count", "3_count", "4_count")
    val perArrayColumns = List("1_per", "2_per", "3_per", "4_per")

    df.withColumn("countArr", array(countArrayColumns.map(col): _*))
      .withColumn("perArr", array(perArrayColumns.map(col): _*))
      .map(row => {
        val countArr = row.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Int]]("countArr")
        val perArr = row.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Int]]("perArr")

        val (position, count, per) = countArr.zipWithIndex
          .filter(row => row._1 > 10 && perArr(row._2) < 100)
          .map(row => (row._2 + 1, row._1, perArr(row._2)))
          .headOption.getOrElse((0, 0, 0))

        (row.getInt(0), count, per, position)
      }).toDF("ID", "count", "per", "slot")
      .show()

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is in Python - Hope you would be able to convert into scala -

```
%python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1=spark.createDataFrame([
(1,3,11,15,3,70,80,150,20),
(2,19,5,15,3,150,80,200,43),
(3,30,15,15,39,55,80,150,200),
(4,8,65,3,3,70,80,150,55)], ["ID","1_count","2_count","3_count","4_count","1_per","2_per","3_per","4_per"])


df1  = df1.withColumn('slot', 
                      F.when(((F.col('1_count') > 10) & (F.col('1_per') < 100)), '1')
                      .when(((F.col('2_count') > 10) & (F.col('2_per') < 100)), '2')
                      .when(((F.col('3_count') > 10) & (F.col('3_per') < 100)), '3')
                      .when(((F.col('4_count') > 10) & (F.col('4_per') < 100)), '4')
                      .otherwise('0'))
df1 = df1.withColumn('count',
                     F.when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('1')),F.col('1_count'))
                     .when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('2')),F.col('2_count'))
                     .when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('3')),F.col('3_count'))
                     .when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('4')),F.col('4_count'))
                     .otherwise('0'))
df1 = df1.withColumn('per',
                     F.when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('1')),F.col('1_per'))
                     .when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('2')),F.col('2_per'))
                     .when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('3')),F.col('3_per'))
                     .when((F.col('slot') == F.lit('4')),F.col('4_per'))
                     .otherwise('0'))
df1 = df1.select('ID', 'count', 'per', 'slot')
df1.show()
```

-------OUTPUT---------

```
+---+-----+---+----+
| ID|count|per|slot|
+---+-----+---+----+
|  1|   11| 80|   2|
|  2|    0|  0|   0|
|  3|   30| 55|   1|
|  4|   65| 80|   2|
+---+-----+---+----+
```

Comment: Hi @dsk . Thanks for your reply and efforts. But my column num is not fixed. I will vary dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

This is my try-

#### 1. Without UDF

#### 2. You can add any number `(count, per)` the solution will work as is

### Load the data provided

```scala
 val cols = Seq("ID", "1_count", "2_count", "3_count", "4_count", "1_per", "2_per", "3_per", "4_per")
    val df1 = Seq(
      (1, 3, 11, 15, 3, 70, 80, 150, 20),
      (2, 19, 5, 15, 3, 150, 80, 200, 43),
      (3, 30, 15, 15, 39, 55, 80, 150, 200),
      (4, 8, 65, 3, 3, 70, 80, 150, 55)
    ) toDF (cols: _*)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      * |ID |1_count|2_count|3_count|4_count|1_per|2_per|3_per|4_per|
      * +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      * |1  |3      |11     |15     |3      |70   |80   |150  |20   |
      * |2  |19     |5      |15     |3      |150  |80   |200  |43   |
      * |3  |30     |15     |15     |39     |55   |80   |150  |200  |
      * |4  |8      |65     |3      |3      |70   |80   |150  |55   |
      * +---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 1_count: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 2_count: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 3_count: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 4_count: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 1_per: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 2_per: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 3_per: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- 4_per: integer (nullable = false)
      */
```

### Create `array<struct>` and filter it using `filter` function (spark >= 2.4.0)

```scala
    val (countCols, perCols) = cols.filter(_ != "ID").partition(_.endsWith("count"))
    val struct = countCols.zip(perCols).map { case (countCol, perCol) =>
      expr(s"named_struct('count', $countCol, 'per', $perCol, " +
        s"'slot', cast(substring_index('$countCol', '_', 1) as int))")
    }

    val processedDf = df1.select($"ID", array(struct: _*).as("count_per"))
        .withColumn("count_per_p", coalesce(
          expr("FILTER(count_per, x -> x.count > 10 and x.per < 100)[0]"),
          expr("named_struct('count', 0,'per', 0, 'slot', 0)")
        ))
        .selectExpr("ID", "count_per_p.*")
    processedDf.show(false)
    processedDf.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+-----+---+----+
      * |ID |count|per|slot|
      * +---+-----+---+----+
      * |1  |11   |80 |2   |
      * |2  |0    |0  |0   |
      * |3  |30   |55 |1   |
      * |4  |65   |80 |2   |
      * +---+-----+---+----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- count: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- per: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- slot: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```